# Time complexity of nested IF statements

Tags: java, if-statement, time-complexity

If we have '`m`' outer IF-ELSE statements and **each** outer IF-ELSE statement contains '`n`' IF-ELSE statements, **then what would be the time complexity of the code?**

For Example:

```
if(Condition 1){
    if(Condition 2){
        //Do something
    }
    .
    .    //'n' inner IF-ELSE statements
    .    
    else{
        //Do something else
    }
}
.
.  //'m' outer IF-ELSE Statements
.
else{
    //Do something else
}
```

Comment: What gets executed in each of the "do something" or "do something else" blocks? That will influence the time complexity of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Time complexity (worst case) will be O(m+n). It will check m conditions for outer else ifs and upon finding the true condition, will check n conditions for the inner else ifs.

Comment: Big-O notation is an Upper Bound Limit. For this question's algorithm, the worst case would be checking all IF statements of "'m' outer" and then checking all IF statements of "'n' inner" the same as two nested loops would work. Meaning complexity would be closer to O(n\*m) and not O(n+m). So if you just change O(m+n) to O(m\*n) in your answer that will be less misleading.

Comment: This (and the above comment) are both incorrect.  Time complexity is in relation to the input.  In this case, the time complexity has _no_ relation to the input.  There aren't any loops or anything, just a fixed number of if statements.  It's [constant time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75940892/208273).

Comment: Consider the example of unlimited nested if statements, where the condition for the outer if statement is met at the last if statement of that definition and condition 2, is met at the last inner if statement of that last outer if statement definition. Will Java runtime instantly iterate over all unlimited if statements checking each condition for outer m and inner n statements and make it O(1)? I bet if you write a code for such an example and try to execute it you will find that it will actually take an unlimited amount of time to finish the code.

Answer (score 0):

The time complexity is **O(1)** (constant time).

In this example, you have *m* * *n* conditionals checked, but those are fixed numbers of conditionals that are hardcoded into the program.  There's no processing of data with size *m* or *n*, such as a loop.  If the data doubles in size, there will still be the same constant number of if statements.  Thus, the time complexity is constant, or O(1).

Answer (score 0):

The Big-O notation of this is NOT O(m+n).

(also, you've managed to explain a nested loop scenario, but used if statements as your code..)

If you're at an apple orchard and you have to check how many apples are hanging in the orchard, but there was a storm and some of the trees may have fallen over during the night...

Then, you'd have to first walk around and check if each tree was up. Each time you got to a tree that was standing - you counted its apples. The trees are the outer loop (btw you explained nested loops but wrote if statements) and the apples are the inner loop....

Big-O analyzes the UPPER BOUND LIMIT of an equation... aka - bigO would be an assessment that assumes every tree is standing and every tree has the maximum amt of apples a tree can possibly hold.

Even though you wrote half your code in English rather than using loops, the answer to your question is Big-O(N^2)

It is NOT (m+n) ... First off - you don't keep both variables, you just use n. Second, it is NOT the two added together. If there were 20 trees in the orchard, none had fallen, and each tree was full of apples and each one could bear a maximum of 50 apples... (would there be 70 apples in the orchard??? No.) There would be 1000 apples.

(The Big-O is not technically constant - ACCORDING TO THE CODE written, yes, it is. However, the paragraph makes for a bit of logic that suggests loops SHOULD be in the code - taking the words "if we have M outer if statements" into account shows it's n^2. The code that's written as an example DOESN'T have multiple outer if statements, though).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).